# Extrude single edge multiple times

Tags: modeling, edges, extrude

I'd like to extrude a single edge into multiple evenly-sized faces in a single action.

As an example, I have this plane:

[image]

With Ctrl Rightclick I can extrude it many times:

[image]

The problem is that these extruded faces aren't evenly spaced (they're different sizes each).

I'd like to create multiple extrusions that are each evenly sized.

Comment: You could enable the LoopTools addon, select the edge loops on each side and right click > Space, but I'm not sure that it's exactly what you want

Comment: whare are you trying to make?